# Nested SQL Queries throws Error while they run in distinct form in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

I have a `SELECT` Query which should have several nested `SELECT` Queries from the same table, but different `WHERE` clauses to produce new columns.

The problem is that each sub query in its single form runs good, but when they turn into sub-queries, MySql throws an ERROR.

Here is My SQL :

```
SELECT user, 
(SELECT SUM(amount) from my_table WHERE type='form1' group by user) as form1,
(SELECT SUM(amount) from my_table WHERE type='form2' group by user) as form2,
(SELECT SUM(amount) from my_table WHERE type='form3' group by user) as form3,
(SELECT SUM(amount) from my_table WHERE type='form4' group by user) as form4,
(SELECT SUM(amount) from my_table WHERE type='form5' group by user) as form5,
(SELECT SUM(amount) from my_table WHERE type='form6' group by user) as form6
from my_table group by user;
```

I want the Query to produce this structure:

```
user | form1 | form2 | form3 | form4 | form5 | form6
     |       |       |       |       |       |
```

How should I edit this SQL?

Comment: You have an extra comma after `as form6`.

Comment: @Barmar, its just a typo in stackoverflow :)

Comment: Then why haven't you corrected it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation:

```
select user,
       sum(case when type = 'form1' then amount end) as form1,
       sum(case when type = 'form2' then amount end) as form2,
       sum(case when type = 'form3' then amount end) as form3,
       sum(case when type = 'form4' then amount end) as form4,
       sum(case when type = 'form5' then amount end) as form5,
       sum(case when type = 'form6' then amount end) as form6
from my_table
group by user;
```

Your error is occurring at least because the subqueries are returning more than one row.  The `group by` in the subqueries pretty much means that they will return more than one row for each user.

Comment: upvoted as this is correct, however for efficiency sake you may consider (a) making the `CASE` value rather than search, and (b) adding an `ELSE 0` to each.